Can't get FFMPEG works in autohotkey
I read the documentation of Run from which I tried this example, but I retrieve nothing in the message box :
command := """C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Portable Softwares\FFMpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe""" . " -i " ;ne pas oublier l'espace à la fin
path1 := """C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Enregistrements videos pro\Point XL Engineering-20240705_140847-Enregistrement de la réunion.mp4""" ; path with spaces


command := command . path1
MsgBox %command%
MsgBox % RunWaitOne(command)

RunWaitOne(command) {
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    ; Execute a single command via cmd.exe
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C " command)
    ; Read and return the command's output
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

I have been trying multiple combinations of double quotes, but I cannot get my mind around it. Can somebody help ?
Thanks,

I finally get it working.
In order to have utf8 characters in command line, I had to use this answer
;"ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libxvid -qscale:v 5 -c:a mp3 -qscale:a 5 output.avi"

command = "C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Portable Softwares\FFMpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

path1 := """C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Enregistrements videos pro\2023.10.23_15.29 Oracle  CSM-converted.mp4"""
path2 := """C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Enregistrements videos pro\output.avi"""


func(command) {
    return ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec(command).StdErr.ReadAll()
}

RunE(command, path1, path2) {
    command := command . " -i " . path1 . " -c:v libxvid -qscale:v 5 -c:a mp3 -qscale:a 5 " . path2
    msgbox % command
    return func(command)
}

msgbox % RunE(command, path1, path2)


Maybe this could give you some start point.
command = "C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Portable Softwares\FFMpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i
path1 = "C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Enregistrements videos pro\Point XL Engineering-20240705_140847-Enregistrement de la réunion.mp4"
path2 = "C:\Users\julien\OneDrive\Enregistrements videos pro\output video name.mp4" ; output path with spaces

func( command ) {
    return % ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec( command ).StdErr.ReadAll()
}
msgbox % RunE( command " " path1 " " path2 )

